# What's wrong with this code? dialog is not a function

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to solve another issue I'm having with autotab. For this site it's just not working, I keep getting autotab is undefined, when everything's being called correctly.

I also notice in the console I'm receiving "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

The block it's referencing is this:

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog( {
    position: ['center'],
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text : "Close",
        "class" : 'closeButtonClass',
        click : function(e) {
            document.getElementById("modalPopup").src = "about:blank";
            $('#dialog-modal').dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong? It's saying the error is on the line that has "click : function(e) {" but that can't be right, as there's no call to .dialog there.

Comment: Have you loaded the library??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dialog()` is not a method within the standard jQuery library; it is part of jQueryUI, which it looks like you have not added to your page. Add the following code to the `head` of your page, after you include `jquery.js`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: I'm loading jQueryUI. Annoyingly though, I created  bare page just for this, with all the JS stuff in the head, and it works. However I try to move it down to the footer with all the rest of the site, and it breaks saying now that autotab isn't a function.

Comment: JS is loaded in order. If you have a script in the `head` which relies on another script which is at the end of the `body`, you'll get that error.

Comment: But the order has been correct all the way through. For example, if you view new.nirvanalight.com/autotab.php this shows it work, in bare form. (JS files are at the bottom). then if you view new.nirvanalight.com/members/login.php and click Sign Up, the DOB fields are set to autotab, no JS errors.. but nothing happens. I can't work out why

Comment: Just revisiting this, as it was a good few months ago. I will mark this as the correct answer, as it was because of ordering. I believe the issue has now been fixed, and I believe it was because there were multiple scripts within a single JS file, that was being affected when being moved elsewhere in the order of the code.